# Is there a .lyx template for DTX (Documented LaTeX sources)?

Tags: dtx

Or, straight-forward instructions for configuring LyX to use `DTX` files?

Or, more generally, what would be a simple Literate Programming system for LyX which would allow the writing of arbitrary source code?

My current project requires writing in Python and OpenSCAD, and it will be necessary to have 4 files and a given command will need to have a version in each:

- .py --- this will be the initial definition as a Python function using `def`
- .scad (first instance) --- this will be imported using `use` and will wrap the Python function in OpenSCAD code
- .scad (second instance) --- this will be imported using `include` which will wrap the OpenSCAD call in more OpenSCAD code and will allow the use of variables to conditionally execute (or not) the Python function
- .scad (example file) --- an example file showing how the final OpenSCAD module would be called

Or, does someone have a simpler suggestion --- the fall-back is using TexWorks or TeXshop, but I'd appreciate some syntactical sugar and support in the form of a pretty GUI.

Comment: No idea of OpenSCAD, nor python, nor your goals, but LyX support via the the Knitr module (need R and knitr R package) literate programming,  primarily for R code, but optionally also python (example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647787/11604)) and other engines. Hope this help.